# Shopify: How to make new products hidden by default?

Tags: shopify

I have a shopify site that is hooked up with Lightspeed via MerchantOS.  I need new products added via MerchantOS to be hidden upon sync/creation.  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Shopify product creation](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product#create/?ref=microapps) via API allows you to define the product visiblity (published / hidden). You should dig into MerchantOS to make sure when doing a POST to create a product at your Shopify store, it has the following property:

```
"published": false
```

Create a new, but unpublished product:

```
POST /admin/products.json
{
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!<\/strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "published": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks.  how would i "dig into" MerchantOS more?  The lightspeed crew installed that for me but I can stare at code and figure out what's happening most of the time...

Comment: @BrockVond can you tell them to take a look at my answer? You have 2 machines speaking to each other. So you need to tell MerchantOS to say something (published: false) to Shopify.

Comment: I can do that - I was hoping there'd be a way for me to go under MerchantOS' hood tho.